# Devel issue - "Rebuild the theme registry on every page load" won't work

Tags: theming, caching

[image]

I use D7. My site is being hosted on a "Shared" Server at Siteground.com. My site doesn't have any CSS/JS aggregation what so ever (see attachment), and I'm sick and tired of clearing the cache after the smallest of the CSS changes.

Many people told me that **installing** Devel **and enabling** "Rebuild the theme registry on every page load" should solve the problem, and will let me see the CSS changes after a refresh (F5/ctrl+r/ctrl+f5), but the fact is that even after I did that and enabled the Theme registry rebuilding option, I still have to clear caches to see the CSS changes, so I'm still stuck with this, and it's indeed frustrating!.

So, why would "Rebuild the theme registry on every page load" won't work? Why do I still need to flush all caches to see the CSS changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a straight solution and not really the best one but it seems that the co-problem; clearing the cache after every css change, was mainly **server-sided**, rather than Drupal sided --- I store at siteground.com and it was a Cpanel tool named "Supercacher" that caused all this mess and apparent lifetime wasting (and yet it raises the chance for good SEO when you site is finished).

Anyway, When you develop, better turn it off in Cpanel.

Btw, this was enough by it's own for me... Neither Devel nor any other external module is needed for this solution to work... Just disable the tool at Cpanel.